# C++ Executable not working from folder, but working from console on Mac

Tags: c++, gcc, allegro, allegro5

I have this strange problem with a game I'm making in c++ with Allegro.

There is a part of the game that uses some images from the source folder.

I compile it through `gcc` and create the executable file `main`, it works fine when I call `./main` from the terminal... The games load every images and works just fine.

But if I open finder, navigate and double click on the same `main` it crashes because it doesn't success on loading the images from the source.
The same thing happens if I try to open it from Instruments too.

The source code folder structure is:

`project:
    |  main  //the executable is in the root of the project folder
    |  /src  //Where all the cpp and h files are stored
    |  /obj  //Where the .o files are stored
    |  item.png //images are also in the root of the project folder`

and the image loading function is the base function of Allegro

```
al_load_bitmap("item.png");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour on macOS. You need a bundle for this to work. It's in the official macOS faq:

http://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/build/macosx.html

Ues a tool called `fixbundle`.

Comment: Uhm... apparently installing allegro through homebrew didn't installed everything and I miss the fixbundle command... I'll try to rebuild allegro source up and hope for the best.

Comment: I built allegro source even with the "make install" at the end but still no fixbundle command... Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I managed to implement a "bundle making thing" into my makefile so now when I make it automagically makes the .app file with all the necessary stuff inside to make it work properly.